# Navigation Bar colides with status bar in swift xcode for iphone 8 simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

I'm working on an iphone app that will be compatible from iphone 6 to the new iphone.
During the process, I've come to a problem where for iphone 8 simulator, the navigation bar's height is too short so the back button overlaps with status bar where in iphone 11, everything looks just fine. How would I go about in fixing this? How would I make the navigation bar look like the one shown in iphone 11? p.s. I've done nothing but link to show the current page when the user presses the button from the previous page. And, of course, I go back when i click on the back button.[image]

Comment: may help this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AppDelegate file you can add this:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    {
      //(by default it is True)
      UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
      // it will prevent overlaping
    }
```

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/translucent)

OR you can add this code in your viewController

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge(rawValue: 0)
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply, but I can't seem to find "translucent" method?

Comment: suggestion for when i can't see neither "istranslucent" nor "translucent" method after UINavigationBar.appearance()?

Comment: Still can't find either "istranslucent" or "translucent"....can't seem to figure out why

Comment: done it but still doesn't show "transluncent" method.